# My ratingbar does not show up after generating signed apk

Tags: android, keystore, ratingbar, signed-apk

I have a rating bar class as follow.

```
class Rating extends FieldAndroid {
@Override
public String register() {
    return register("rating");
}

@Override
protected Object createControl() {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final RatingBar ratingBar = new android.widget.RatingBar(getContext());
    ratingBar.setStepSize((float) 1.0);
    if (getEditable())

        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                        boolean fromUser) {

                ratingBar.setRating(rating);
            }
        });
    layout.addView(ratingBar, params);
    return layout;
}
```

It is working perfectly, when I install the apk, through run in any emulator. But when I generate the signed apk with my keystore, my ratingbar does not show up.

Do you have any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Proguard enable ??

Comment: yes.
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.pro', 'proguard-rules.pro

Comment: Nope. Did you add `minifyEnabled true` ?

Comment: it is false for dev flavors.

Comment: for release flavors ?

Comment: it is true for release

Answer (score 1):

Open your **`proguard-rules.pro`**

Add

```
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

**FYI**

If you want to add **`Rating`** class then

```
-keep public class yourPackage.Rating
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

**NOTE**

Your code will works if you set  **`minifyEnabled false`**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
```

Comment: I tried this and it is not working.
Here is some part of my gradle. 

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.pro', 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Here is proguard-rules.pro
-keep class pt.santandertotta.mobileparticulares.mobile.Rating {
    public private *;
}

Comment: @SparksSh add `-keep class * {
    public private *;
}`

Comment: @SparksSh If same problem then  `release { minifyEnabled false`

Comment: Did you set false?

Comment: The destination of my package was not reachable through another class, that made the app crashed.
Now it is working. xD